# EConvertError when I Filter my sqlServer database with FireDac

Tags: sql-server, delphi, firedac

I'm using `Delphi 10.2.3 Tokyo` with `FireDac` , and setting a connection to an `SqlServer(2016)` database , when i set the filter `Date_Document` field in my query I get **"could not parse SQL timesamp string"** Exception.

BTW:Data type of `Date_Document` is `datetime`.

```
procedure TfrmMain.fltDateEdt2Change(Sender: TObject);
var dat1,dat2:TSQLTimeStamp;
begin
if (fltDateEdt1.Text<>'  /  /    ') and (fltDateEdt2.Text<>'  /  /    ') then
 begin
 if fltDateEdt1.Date<fltDateEdt2.Date then
  try
   dat1:=DateTimeToSQLTimeStamp(fltDateEdt1.Date);
   dat2:=DateTimeToSQLTimeStamp(fltDateEdt2.Date);
   comps.qryMain.Filter:=format('%s>= %s AND %s<=%s',  ['DATE_DOCUMENT',SQLTimeStampToStr('YYYY-MM-DD',dat1).QuotedString,'DATE_DOCUMENT',SQLTimeStampToStr('YYYY-MM-DD',dat2).QuotedString]);
comps.qryMain.Filtered:=true;
  except

  end;
  end
else
  begin
  comps.qryMain.Filtered:=false;
  comps.qryMain.Filter:='';
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Don't you want to use FireDAC expression escaping instead of this manual string building?

Comment: How ? I tryed many ways but it does not work I get always that exception

Comment: Could be a regional settings issue. Did you set TFormatsettings date related parameters?

Comment: Like e.g. `'DATE_DOCUMENT >= {dt 2018-06-30 00:00:00} AND DATE_DOCUMENT <= {dt 2018-06-30 23:59:59}'` where date portion you replace by the required date time (the format is obvious and [described here](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Preprocessing_Command_Text_(FireDAC)#Escape_Sequences)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use [**escape sequences**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Preprocessing_Command_Text_(FireDAC)#Escape_Sequences) in such case. Like for example (assuming that **DATE_DOCUMENT** column is of [**DATETIME**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime-transact-sql) data type as you mentioned):

```
comps.qryMain.Filter := Format('DATE_DOCUMENT >= {dt %s 00:00:00} AND DATE_DOCUMENT <= {dt %s 23:59:59}', [
  FormatDateTime('yyyy-mm-dd', fltDateEdt1.Date),
  FormatDateTime('yyyy-mm-dd', fltDateEdt2.Date)
]);
```

The point of making such filter string is that you let FireDAC convert described date time format into DBMS' native one by only replacing date portion with the given date time in such specified format.

Of even better, I would simply write a handler for the [**OnFilterRecord**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Data.DB.TDataSet.OnFilterRecord) event.

Comment: You're welcome! Anyway, I've modified your filter a bit. From the original it differs in time portion which covers the day up to its end (hence the used time 23:59:59).